# A strange case of property-inheritance behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Maybe the title is not so clear, but this is what I'm experiencing:

- I have created a base-form which contains an OK and a Cancel button (which is called BaseOkCancelButtonForm)
  This form also has some properties which look like this:

  ```
      [Browsable (true)]
      [Category ("Design")]
      [DesignerSerializationVisibility (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
      public string OkButtonText
      {
          get
          {
              return btnOk.Text;
          }
          set
          {
              btnOk.Text = value;
          }
      }

     [Browsable (true)]
      [Category ("Design")]
      [DefaultValue (true)]
      [DesignerSerializationVisibility (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
      public bool OkButtonVisible
      {
          get
          {
              return btnOk.Visible;
          }
          set
          {
              btnOk.Visible = value;
          }
      }

      [Browsable (true)]
      [Category ("Design")]
      [DesignerSerializationVisibility (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
      public string CancelButtonText
      {
          get
          {
              return btnCancel.Text;
          }
          set
          {
              btnCancel.Text = value;
          }
      }

      [Browsable (true)]
      [Category ("Design")]
      [DefaultValue (true)]
      [DesignerSerializationVisibility (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
      public bool CancelButtonVisible
      {
          get
          {
              return btnCancel.Visible;
          }
          set
          {
              btnCancel.Visible = value;
          }
      }
  ```

Now, this is what is happening:
I create a new form which inherits from my BaseOkCancelButtonForm.

When I modify the CancelButtonText property of my inherited form, and I rebuild the project, everything is going as expected:  the Text of the Cancel button remains as the text that i've set.
However, when I do the same for the CancelButtonVisible property, things go wrong.
When I set the CancelButtonVisible property to false, and I rebuild the project, then VS.NET resets the value of this property back to true. :?

For one reason or another, the changed value is not persisted by the designer ?
Is this know behaviour ?  Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it seems that this does work when I make the CancelButton on my base form protected.
But, I do not want to do that.
Besides, it should not be necessary to do that as well ...  (And changing the text property of the button does not require the button to be protected, like it should be)...

Weird.